# Excel - making the answer different colors automatically

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to subtract cell 7B from 6B. If the total is greater than 0, the answer should be black, or if it is less than 0 I'd like cell 8B to be red. How can I do this?

Here is an example of my sheet:

[image: Example of my sheet]

Comment: he wants the number that is less than the Expected number at 27% to be red and higher black.  It is the opposite with this formula

Comment: Are you critiquing your own question?  Don’t do that; just [edit] the question to fix it.  Currently, your question is a mess. (1) There are no such thing as cells 6B, 7B and 8B.  You probably mean B6, B7 and B8. (2) Your screen image isn’t very useful if you don’t (a) show which rows are 6, 7 and 8, and (b) show what result you want to get. (3) The word “total” doesn’t apply when you’re talking about subtracting or comparing numbers.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) You say you want to subtract B7 (which is 5) from B6 (which is 27), which yields 22, which is greater than 0, so “the answer should be black.”  But you say if “the number [that] is less than the Expected number at 27%” (as 5 is less than 27), it should be red.  Please fix ([edit]) your question to include a clear and consistent statement of what you want.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Format the formula cell as follows:

```
#,##0_);[Red]#,##0
```

[image]

Comment: But I want it to automatically do it.  I don't want to have to go in and change it myself.

Comment: ok I did that and it does change color but it is opposite of what he wants.  He wants it black if it is higher and red lower.  Now it puts anything higher in red.  I know I am an idiot with this but....

Comment: [Please don't post images of text.](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408)  Screenshots of Excel worksheets are pretty, but this answer would be better if you included the format string as copy-and-pastable text.

Comment: @Bradyt  It is a **standard format**, the red replaces the minus sign.

Comment: @ Scott..................it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to format a value of a cell is by using *Conditional formatting*.

In the home meny, select the cells which need formatting and select *conditional formatting* and the equation you want.

[image]

You can add more than one to each cell. If you select *equal to* and set it to 27. You can then choose how it should show 27.
With the same cells still selected, you can do it again, this time selecting "greater than" and enter 27 again. Now everything above 27 will have this formatting. Same procedure of course for "less than".